# How to find sql error code in vbscript adodb.command.execute for "create login"

Tags: sql-server-2008, vbscript, adodb

I'm trying to find the error code when attempting to create a login using an adodb.command object.

If the "create login" succeeds, an adoRecord object is created.
If it fails, no ado object if created.

I would like to display and log the sql server error of the failure.  The Err object is empty on failed execution.

The code:

```
tsqlcmd.CommandText = "CREATE LOGIN " & uname & " WITH PASSWORD = '" & upw & "'"
tsqlcmd.ActiveConnection = conn

On Error Resume Next
SET adoRec = tsqlcmd.Execute()
' How to I find the sql error ? 
IF Err <> 0 THEN
  serr.Number = Err.Number
  serr.Description = Err.Description
  serr.Source = Err.Source
  serr.HelpContext = Err.HelpContext
  createLogin = false

  errmsg = "createLogin: ADODB Create Command Error: " & Hex(serr.Number) & vbCrLf & _
          "Desc: " & serr.Description & vbCrLf & _
          serr.Source & vbCrLf
  'Fake logging
  MsgBox(errmsg)
  EXIT FUNCTION
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

> **ExecuteComplete Event**
>
> The ExecuteComplete event is called after a
> command has finished executing.
>
> Syntax ExecuteComplete RecordsAffected, pError, adStatus, pCommand,
> pRecordset, pConnection
>
> Parameters RecordsAffected  A Long value indicating the number of records affected by the command.
>
> pError  An Error object. It describes the error that occurred if the value of
>
> adStatus is adStatusErrorsOccurred; otherwise it is not set.
>
> adStatus An EventStatusEnum status value. When this event is called, this
> parameter is set to adStatusOK if the operation that caused the event
> was successful, or to adStatusErrorsOccurred if the operation failed.
> Before this event returns, set this parameter to adStatusUnwantedEvent
> to prevent subsequent notifications.
>
> pCommand  The Command object that was executed. Contains a Command
> object even when calling Connection.Execute or Recordset.Open without
> explicitly creating a Command, in which cases the Command object is
> created internally by ADO.
>
> pRecordset  A Recordset object that is the
> result of the executed command. This Recordset may be empty. You
> should never destroy this Recordset object from within this event
> handler. Doing so will result in an Access Violation when ADO tries to
> access an object that no longer exists.
>
> pConnection  A Connection object. The connection over which the operation was executed.
>
> Remarks
>
> An ExecuteComplete event may occur due to the Connection.Execute,
> Command.Execute, Recordset.Open, Recordset.Requery, or
> Recordset.NextRecordset methods.

Comment: @searchandresq `mk:@MSITStore:C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio\MSDN\2001OCT\1033\ado270.chm::/htm/mdevtexecutecomplete.htm`

Comment: I meant, with the answer :) . Could you please add it to your answer?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ It's a link to a file on my harddrive. It's MSDN SDK Help.

Comment: It Windows Help. Everyone should have it available. It's not Visual Studio Help. It's Windows SDK.

Comment: I just need to get Wscript.CreateObject to create the object with the event handler instead of returning empty

Comment: ExecuteComplete  does not appear to work for adodb objects in vbscript.